# Replace character in all columns using Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Is it possible to simply change character in name of tables columns? At the moment columns have seperator - and I want to change it with underscore (_) . Is it possible to do it easy with 1 click or should I go through all tables and change it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know oracle SQL data modeler. If you have access to SQL*Plus or another developer tool, you can run script, it will change all columns of tables in your schema:

```
begin
  for i in (select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns) loop
    if instr(i.column_name, 'A') > 0 then
       execute immediate 'alter table ' || i.table_name || ' rename column ' || 
          i.column_name || ' to ' || replace(i.column, 'A', 'B');
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Here 'A' is symbol that you want to replace and 'B' - new symbol to use. But be careful, such scripts can be dangerous. Try it on test schema first.